# Will SanDisk 64GB SATA Internal 2.5" SSD work with SATA II

Tags: ssd, sata

Just a quick question,

I have this motherboard [asrock m3a785gmh](http://www.asrock.com/MB/AMD/M3A785GMH128M/index.asp) and I'm planning to purchase a [SanDISK SSD](http://www.microdirect.co.uk/Home/Product/56174/SanDisk-64GB-SATA-Internal-2-5-inch-SSD). Just want to make sure these two are compatible? I can not see a reason why they would not be, just want to get some reassurance :)

Answer (score 1):

SATA is fully backwards compatible so it should work just fine. If i read it right, the SSD is still SATA 1, and i dont think that that SSD is the right choice. You would be better of buying an SATA 3 SSD.

Comment: Would a SATA 3 SSD work with my motherboard?

Comment: That SSD is a SATA 3 device. See the same SSD over at [Newegg](http://www.newegg.com/Product/Product.aspx?Item=N82E16820171645).

Comment: You're right. It will work just fine then